# Hetzner Cloud private networking between projects/accounts

Tags: networking, vpn, cloud, hetzner

we are working on migration of our stack to Hetzner Cloud and trying to figure out the way to separate our dev/monitoring/prod resources across multiple projects/accounts in order to have fine grain access management and isolation. We are struggling to find an option that would allow us to connect private networks from either multiple projects belonging to the same account or multiple accounts.

We have checked out vSwitch option, however it won't allow connection of multiple cloud networks. Any hint or advice is highly appreciated. So far we can't see any option but putting all the resources under same account, project and network within it.

Comment: hetzner has a great free support, which is at this point a better way imho

Comment: yap, I'm just looking at this .... its a big let down that they dont have somekind of an vpc peering like aws...but possibly we could mitigate that with an openvpn site to site connection...

Comment: Hetzner is one the best providers. Despite the fact there is no direct implementation for inter-project networking, you can always create a VPN to connect networks of different projects. It is not a downside. I believe AWS and the similar sell users too many things they do not have, and users end up paying too much for things they never use or need.